# MapQuest via C#

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, mapquest

I am trying to access to MapQuest via a Winforms C# application.

I can't find any help on how I can make a WebRequest (via JSON, XML or Text). How do I embed my Application Key in that request? Or do I have to perform a login-request or what?

Has anyone perhaps used this API in C#, C++ or Java? I could use some start-help as I can't find any infos on how to do this.

There was a C# .Net API but it is deprecated now and they recommend using WebRequests.

I hope someone can help me! If you need more information just ask. Thanks!

Comment: Just for curiosity, why don't you use google? or bing?

Comment: The problem is that I want to optimize my route. Even more! I just want to enter the destinations and it will make the routes for me. MapQuest provides already a route optimization but I have to add some functionality to the application.

Comment: But I see it won't be as easy as I want it to be. I actually just want to order the stops I have to do. Do you know if there is an easy way?

Comment: Check google maps or bing. The api and the community will assist you to do what ever you want.

Comment: The problem is that they have some policies in their agreements that I don't want. I tought MapQuest was a really big community too.

Comment: @ElMac I too have been using MapQuest API.  I would say Google definitely has a much, much bigger community than MapQuest.  MapQuest has been some what of a pain in the rear.